# Laravel Eloquent with syntax - which of these is more effecient

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

With regards to Laravel Eloquent queries and eager loading, which of these queries is most efficient? Does it make a diference?

```
$data = Model::with('relationship')
            ->with('relationship.content')
            ->with('meta')
            ->with('meta.meta_type')
            ->first
```

as opposed to :

```
    $data = Model::with('relationship', 'relationship.content', 'meta', 'meta.meta_type')
            ->first;
```

Comment: This is not the best test, but you could always use the browser dev tools to measure the load times.

Comment: `Does it make a diference?` NO

Comment: Probably: `with(['relationship.content', 'meta.meta_type'])` - You might save one or two microseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* a difference. Is it the difference you're thinking of?

#### Is there a difference in the query/queries performed, or the data returned?

Answer: **No.**

All of the calls to `with()` will be combined into a single set of eager loads, which will be parsed and queried when the query is completed upon calling `first()`. Both code examples will be turned into the same set of eager loads, and the resulting models should be identical.

#### Is there a performance difference?

Answer: **Yes, a small one.**

The performance difference is very small, and would be considered a micro-optimization by many (meaning that it is only worth optimizing if you are working at a significant scale).

Each call to `with()` will determine the type of value you've passed (one or more strings or an array), validate and parse the relationships including finding any nested, and then merge the results with any existing relationships from previous `with()` calls.

If you're interested in writing the most optimal code, the first and largest step you can take is to only call `with()` once:

```
$data = Model::with('relationship', 'relationship.content', 'meta', 'meta.meta_type')
    ->first();
```

If the value supplied to the call contains one or more strings, PHP's `func_get_args()` is called. If you pass an array, the array is used directly. That's the next optimization we can make: use an array.

```
$data = Model::with(['relationship', 'relationship.content', 'meta', 'meta.meta_type'])
    ->first();
```

Finally, when you pass a nested relationship to Laravel, both relationships will be included in the eager load. Including both `parent` and `parent.child` relationships is redundant.

Your call - still functionally identical - can be reduced to:

```
$data = Model::with(['relationship.content', 'meta.meta_type'])
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not make a difference.

The `with()` method accepts either a single relation or relations.

Both of the things you have done is the same thing.

Here's how it works behind the scenes:

```
/**
 * Begin querying a model with eager loading.
 *
 * @param  array|string  $relations
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
 */
public static function with($relations)
{
    return (new static)->newQuery()->with(
        is_string($relations) ? func_get_args() : $relations
    );
}
```